# I got a token invalid error even though I have a token connected

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, discord, discord.js

[image: error]

I got this error message on heroku and I'm not sure how to fix it, since my code is very basic. I've been following a tutorial on how to set my discord bot up 24/7. If anyone can help me fix this, much appreciated! :)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
    ]
});


bot.on("ready", function () {
    console.log("Hello!");
});

bot.login(process.env.token);
```

Above is my code in index.js and below is package.json

```
{
  "name": "discordbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.11.0"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you provided valid token in heroku value and value name is exactly "token" and not "ToKen" for example?

Comment: Try to do `console.log(process.env.token)` to see if you really are able to get the token.

Comment: Make sure you do `require('dotenv').config()` to load your env variables into `process.env` before trying to use them, since you're using `dotenv`.